How do I change the index that CHOOSE starts to select from, i.e. not 1?
This is how my case section is setup:

Column M, the red 1is the user input. Ideally, when I change that value to any of the values in cells G554:K554 the value in cell M555 should show the corresponding description. That's not the behaviour I am getting.
So in other words, when I change M554 to 5, M555 should read Year 5. This is what happens now:

When I change M554 to 8, M555 should read Year 8, instead it throws an error:

This is the formula in M555:
=CHOOSE(M$554,G555,H555,I555,J555,K555,L555)

How do I fix this?
Also, it would be great if it doesn't throw an error once I input a value outside of the pre-defined case range, so if you could solve that for me as well that would be great :)
Btw, this all works if the Case values are 1 - 5, then I don't have any issues. It just doesn't work for any values higher than 5.

Why it has to be choose when you can do it with FILTER() function: =FILTER(G555:L555,M554=G554:L554) or if you want to use CHOOSE() then --> =CHOOSE(M554-4,G555,H555,I555,J555,K555,L555) also note that the CHOOSE() will work as long as there is no lower value than 5, the reason behind to use M554-4 to index the values as per the subsequent positions. Or could have used a simple HLOOKUP() --> =HLOOKUP(M554,G554:L555,2,0)

Since it's only one value, you can also use =XLOOKUP(M$554,G554:L554,G555:L555,"")

Use any one of the followings as per your Excel Versions:


• Using FILTER()
=FILTER(G555:L555,M554=G554:L554,"")


• Or Using HLOOKUP()
=HLOOKUP(M554,G554:L555,2,0)


• Or if you intent to use CHOOSE() then --> =CHOOSE(M554-4,G555,H555,I555,J555,K555,L555) also note that the CHOOSE() will work as long as there is no lower value than 5, the reason behind to use M554-4 to index the values as per the subsequent positions.

Screenshot to show all the results for the years:



When I tried the CHOOSE($M$554-4,G555,H555,I555,J555,K555,L555), it gave me a #VALUE error.

When I use the HLOOKUP function, when I try values 8 & 9, I get an error.

@marcamillion I have shown with 9 and have shown a screenshot as well not getting any error. It works for me, can you show me a screenshot of the error. Also without testing I have not posted the answer
